# How to read a file character by character and then store them into a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have this project in C for school, and I have a problem. I've read pretty much all the topics about this question but none of them answered my question, that's why I'm asking for your help...
I've created a structure in which there is a pointer to an array of character, and I have a file with int and char.

I would like to create a function read_file that would read this file character by character, and then store them into a dynamically allocated array. But first I don't know how to read a file character by character, and second I don't know how to put these characters into the array...

Here is what I've written so far :

```
char* main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE *p_file;
  char* code = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
  char* p = code;
  p_file = fopen(argv[1],"rb+");
  while((ch=getc(p_file)) != EOF){
    *p++ = (char)fgetc(p_file);
  } 
  return code;
  free(code);
```

Could you light me up or send me to a link that could help ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please post your code what you have tried.

Comment: I suggest you post what you have done when you have time to [read the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and can upload the code.

Comment: If you can't copy/paste the code from your VM then you could probably use a shared folder, a USB stick, a cloud storage provider or an e-mail program to exchange the source file. There are many possibilities to exchange data. (How do you plan to send your source code to the teacher?)

Comment: I've suceeded ! My code is up !

Comment: The first thing to note is the definition of `main` must be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, and so it must return `int` too, not `char *`. The memory won't be `free`d because `main` has already returned (although the system will `free` it). Also, the definition `int ch;` is missing, and you read from the file twice instead of assigning `*p++ = ch;`

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation on fread() and/or fgetc() about reading. 
About the array , well, it depends, if it an array of char (e.g. char arr[100]) then you can put them in there as you proceed reading them. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tested code below.

Include headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Function:

```
char* readFile(const char const* filename)
{
    FILE* fh = fopen(filename, "r");
    char* result = NULL;

    if (fh != NULL) {
        size_t size = 1;

        while (getc(fh) != EOF) {
            size++;
        }

        result  = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
        fseek(fh, 0, SEEK_SET); //Reset file pointer to begin

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            result[i] = (char) getc(fh);
        }

        result[size - 1] = '\0';
        fclose(fh);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
char* result = readFile("test.txt");

if (result != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", result);
    free(result);
}
```

Check this:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks it seems to work well !! Nonetheless I've got a few questions ! What fseek does ? I've never used it before... and also what is the (char) in front of getc for ?

Comment: @RaphaelJaafari `fseek` change position on file pointer, when we read by getc we move internal file pointer, `fseek(fh, 0, SEEK_SET);` just move this to begin, more here - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/.
`getc` return int with char code so i change variable type to char. It should work automatic but in C clarity is important.